# Calculate Euclidean distance matrix in C

Tags: c, matlab, code-translation

I would like to convert this code which is written in MATLAB to C:

```matlab
matrix = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 10]
dis=zeros(9);
for i=1:3
    for j=1:3
        dis(i,j)=sqrt(sum (abs((matrix(i,:)-matrix(j,:))))^2);
    end
end
```

The output is as follows:

```
    0    9   19
    9    0   10
   19   10    0
```

Here is what I came up with in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

  double distance[3][3] = {0};
  double myArray[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4 , 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

      distance[i][j] = sqrt(pow(myArray[i] - myArray[j], 2));

    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

      printf("%f ", distance[i][j]);
      if (j == 2) {
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but it displays an empty array:

```
0 0 0                                                     
0 0 0                                                                                       
0 0 0
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: A couple of things. Firstly, you shouldn't use `int` type for doing stuff like sqrt/division. You should use `float` or `double` instead.

Secondly, and more importantly, you aren't actually storing the variable `distance` anywhere. You are just overwriting it each iteration and not doing anything with it. I am guessing you want to store it in the array called distance

Comment: Why, in your matlab code, are you computing : `sqrt(your_number^2)` ? It's useless, just write `your_number` instead. I guess that there is already something wrong in your matalb code.

Comment: I calculate `your_number^2` and then i apply `sqrt` like in C `sqrt(pow(your_number, 2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

1. I think, your input data for the matrix is supposed to be `matrix = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 10]`, however input data is different in your code (observe the last element; `10` in assignment becomes `9` in your code).
2. Those points, I think, are spatial (like x, y & z coordinates). So, you need a third loop; first for points in the outer loop `point_1 = { 1, 2, 3 }, ...` etc, second for points in the inner loop `... point_2 = { 4, 5, 6 }...` etc, and a third one for three coordinates `x = 1, y = 2, z = 3`.
3. `sqrt` returns a double. You'd better cast the returning value to int like `(int)`.
4. As @sahwahn pointed; you compute the distance but never save the value.

Your nested loop structure may look like;

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        int temp = 0;

        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            temp += (int)sqrt(pow(myArray[i][k] - myArray[j][k], 2));
        }

        distance[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

BTW; formula for a true distance computation in spatial coordinates is:
`square root of (the sum of the squares of (the coordinate difference))`, not `the sum of (square root of (the squares of (the coordinate difference)))`.

Because I was unsure about the assignment, I stick to the info given in the question. Logically, for a true distance computation, your inner loop needs to be;

```
double temp = 0.0f;

for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    temp += pow(myArray[i][k] - myArray[j][k], 2);
}

distance[i][j] = (int)sqrt(temp);
```

Comment: Why use of `int temp` and `(int)`?  Would not `double temp = 0;` and no cast make more sense?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica : The sample output is integer, that's why I thought they ought to be converted to int.